# .htaccess MAMP difference to live environment

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, mamp

I'm building my site on MAMP, after a couple of days I finally got an .htaccess file to work after my will. But now when I upload to live environment it doesn't behave the same! Is there different versions? Is it because of error in my file that MAMP handles automatic?

If not these special files then use default RewriteRule. scripts/images/mediacontent/services/robot.txt works but **NOT (login.php,hybridauth,blog)**

```
#start
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# main site
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/scripts/(.*\.js)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/styles/(.*\.css)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/images/(.*\.jpg|.*\.png|.*\.gif)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mediacontent/(.*\.jpg|.*\.png)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/services/(.*\.php)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/login\.php$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/hybridauth/$ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blog/$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/robot.txt$ 

RewriteRule (\w+) index.php?page=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: For the stuff that doesn't work I get "302 Moved Temporarily"

Answer (score 0):

With `\w+`, you don't capture the complete request but only some part of it.

From [Escape sequences](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php)

> \w
>       any "word" character
>
> A "word" character is any letter or digit or the underscore character

This means, dots `.`, slashes `/`, hyphens `-` or any other special character beside underscore `_` are not included.

From the conditions it seems, you want to exclude all existing files and directories from the rule. You can achieve the same with

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php?page=$0 [L]
```

This rule captures the complete path, including any special characters, and passes this to `index.php`. But it also excludes all real files like Javascript sources, CSS files, images, and so on.

Comment: did the same as mine but with a lot less code :)
The issue still occurs in folders hybridauth and blog. Can it have something to do with the content in those folders?

blog - wordpress folder with permalinks. 
hybridauth - has an index.php file that should capture logins. 

these folders and files are ignored and I'm shown a /index.php?page= result

Comment: Going for http://www.mysite.com/blog/index.php gives me a "500 Internal Server Error" and http://www.mysite.com/hybridauth/ gives "302 Moved Temporarily"

Comment: Now it finally worked. I deleted all files on the live environment and then uploaded again. Must be some strange things that was added in the first upload.

Answer (score 0):

After removing all .htaccess files I notices that the issues was not in the rewrite.

I deleted all files on the server and uploaded it again and now it works.

Note to self: Use a good FTP application.